# CVS can't get latest files

Tags: version-control, cvs, tortoisecvs

I have a weird problem I haven't seen before. I modified a file in our repository and committed as I usually do but now when I do a history the version shown as current is the previous version.

1.180 oldFile
1.181 my new changes

but 1.180 is marked current.  Any ideas? I tried doing a fresh checkout and cvs update -A but still the file status indicates it's at version 1.180

See the screen shot here:

http://www.mediafire.com/imageview.php?quickkey=njtmro4n24z&thumb=4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case others see this.  What I did to solve it was stop the cvs services and clean the temp files. Then I restarted and did an update. Then I got the 1.181 file version properly.